# Laravel 5.6 - Factory Relations infinite seeding

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I defined a factory in order to seed tables with *faker*. Following the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/database-testing#writing-factories), I implemented it as showed, like this:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Item::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'codice' => $faker->word,
        'data_acquisto' => $faker->date('Y-m-d'),
        [...] // Other stuff
        // Relations
        'componente_id' => function() {
            return factory(App\Componente::class)->create()->id;
        },
    'tipologia_id' => function() {
        return factory(App\Tipologia::class)->create()->id;
    },
    'condizione_id' => function() {
        return factory(App\Condizione::class)->create()->id;
    },
    'locazione_id' => function() {
        return factory(App\Locazione::class)->create()->id;
    },
    'fornitore_id' => function() {
        return factory(App\Fornitore::class)->create()->id;
    },
    'parent_id' => function() {
        return factory(App\Item::class)->create()->id;
    }
     ];
 });
```

When I launch it with `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed`, framework starts to seed the destination tables, but it being stuck in the relation seeding phase (`factory(App\Componente::class)->create()->id`). Apparently resulting in a some sort of infinite/recursive process (generating thousands of records), until the task crashes due to an overflow.

By googling around, I noticed different approaches from many devs, but seems that others experienced this problem like me. Someone tried to indicate the max number in the factory argument:

```
// Ex. 5 max
return factory(App\Componente::class, 5)->create()->id;
```

And the Laravel doc doesn't mention it. But in this way, it throws another exception:

> Property [id] does not exist on this collection instance.

Either if the migration results like this:

```
Schema::create('componente', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id'); // <- ID exists!
    $table->string('tipo');
    [...] // Other stuff
}
```

About this, I read about the collection specification, i.e. the use of `first()`. But I don't get how to avoid this scenario. I mean, if I use `first()` in the statement, how can it generates the number of required rows if `first()` returns only the first collection occurrence?

At last, I just need to create 3 rows of this one, so how can I approach it?

Thanks in advance everyone for help.

**UPDATE**

Here's **ComponenteFactory.php**

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

// Definizione dati test
$factory->define(App\Componente::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'tipo' => $faker->word,
        'descrizione' => $faker->optional()->sentence,
        'garanzia' => $faker->optional()->text,
        'note' => $faker->optional()->sentence
    ];
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your `App\Componente` factory?

Comment: Hi @chin, I added it in the question above.

Comment: Are you sure it gets stuck in the relation with the componente? Can you show us the other relations of your `App\Item` factory?

Comment: I added them. Dunno, It gets stuck in every way, I tried the exclusion of the other ones too, with the same result. I just noticed that if I set a limit number of records, It generates them correctly but throws the missing property exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your `parent_id` relationship.

```
return factory(App\Item::class)->create()->id;
```

Since the parent is another item, it will create a parent and keep going on creating parents after parents for the new items, which will cause an infinite loop.

To fix this, you may use a random factor to see if you generate a parent or not.

For example:

```
'parent_id' => function () {
    return mt_rand(0, 100) % 2 == 0 ? factory(App\Item::class)->create()->id : null;
}
```

Therefore, when generating the parent relationship, there's a 50% that it will stop the chain.

Comment: @LucaCattide No problem! Have a nice day :)